# Is every continuous function also uniformly continuous?

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

I have a function $f:[c, a]\cup(a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that on $[c, a]$ $f$ is continuous and on $(a, b]$ again f is continuous but it is given that $f(a)\neq f(a+)=lim_{h\rightarrow0} f(a+h)$ and i know that $f(a)$ and $f(a+)$ both exists and are finite real numbers

Comment: Whatever $f(a^+)$ is, define a new function $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ except at $a$, where $g(a) = f(a^+)$. It is easy to see that $g$ is continuous, hence uniformly continuous if $a,b$ are finite. Now $f$ is just a restriction of $g$, so the proposition follows, since given $\epsilon > 0$ we can take the $\delta$ obtained by applying uniform continuity of $g$, and use it for $f$.

Answer (score 0):

What about $\sin\frac{1}{x-a}$?

Comment: $sin\{\frac{1}{x-a}\}$ is not defined at $x=a$ i mean it is not known to us

Comment: Your hypothesis states that it need not be defined at $a$.

Comment: My function is piecewise continuous, i.e $f:[c, a]\cup (a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(a),$ $f(c),$ $f(a^+)$ and $f(b)$ are all finite but $f(a)\neq f(a^+)$

Comment: You need continuity at $a$, or $\sin\frac{1}{x-a}$ is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: $\sin(1/(x-a))$ has no limit as $x \to a+$.  I would assume $f(a+)$ is meant to be the one-sided limit, otherwise the question is pointless -- allowing $f(a+)$ to be arbitrarily defined.

Comment: My argument is that only in the interval $(a, b]$ $f$ can't be uniformly continuous?

Comment: Here $f(a^+)$ is known to me. It is a finite real number

Comment: Standard notation is $f(a+)=\lim_{x \to a+}f(x).$

Comment: Yes. Now whether $f$ is uniformly continuous in $(a, b]?$

Comment: Interpreting $f(a^+)$ as a limit actually gives you f is continuous on $[a,b]$, which does not feel like what is intended, but boundedness and continuity on a closed interval would give you your result. I interpreted this as $f(x)$ is finite arbitrarily close to $a$, with no mention of limit.

Comment: We have $f(a)\neq f(a^+),$ but it is given that both are finite numbers

Answer (score 0):

$sin (1/x)$ on$(0,1]$ satisfies the conditions but is not uniformly continuous.

Edit: what about $x^{1/2}$ over $(0,1]

Comment: Existence of finite $f(a+)$ means there is a one-sided limit.  $\sin(1/x)$ has no limit as $x \to 0+$.

Comment: Aside from the obvious fact that $x^{1/2}$ is continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$ and,hence, uniformly continuous, we can show directly using  $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2 \leqslant |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| = |x-y|.$ If $|x-y| < \delta = \epsilon^2$ then $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| < \epsilon.$